# Which way of specifiying my beans in spring-integration.xml is better?

Tags: spring-integration, javabeans, spring-bean

I have two different ways of declaring a spring integration bean. They both seem to work. I'm using the Spring STS Eclipse based IDE.

This way:

```
<bean id="int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain"
        class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <property name="trapException" value="true"></property>
        <property name="onFailureExpression" value="#root"></property>
        <property name="failureChannel" ref="errorChannel"></property>
</bean>
```

or this way:

```
<int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <property name="trapException" value="true" />
        <property name="onFailureExpression" value="#root" />
        <property name="failureChannel" ref="errorChannel" />
    </bean>
</int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Which way is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the target `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` it doesn't matter. Works well, as you noticed already.

Only the difference that the second declaration is *nested* and the final bean is visible only from the `<int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>` context.

The first definition is top-level global bean, which is visible everywhere and can be reused from other bean as well.

You can find more info about Inner Beans in the [Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inner-beans).